# Boostrap navbar button not working in Facebook app

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, facebook

I have a website using bootstrap, the navbar menu button works perfectly on most browsers, But doesn't work in Facebook app(Iframe). You can test it by clicking on any links in this post using Facebook app: https://www.facebook.com/xekhongdotcom/posts/438728659825253?notif_t=like&notif_id=1495129683629803

Can anybody help?
Thanks!
Here is code of navbar:
    
        
            
            
                
                    Toggle navigation Menu 
                
                mysite.com
                my slogan</p>-->

```
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="hidden">
                    <a href="#page-top"></a>
                </li>
                <li class="page-scroll">
                    <a href="#taxi">item1</a>
                </li>
                <li class="page-scroll">
                    <a href="#truck">item2</a>
                </li>
                <li class="page-scroll">
                    <a href="#support">item3</a>
                </li>
                <!--
                <li class="page-scroll">
                    <a href="#compare-price">item4</a>
                </li>-->
                <li class="page-scroll">
                    <a href="#register-car">item5</a>
                </li>
                <li class="page-scroll">
                    <a href="#about">item6</a>
                </li>
                <li class="page-scroll">
                    <a href="#contact">item7</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: will you please elaborate what you want to achieve? what is that code for?What is that link? given is not that sufficient

Comment: 1. that link is to the post which contain link to my website xekhong.com. this is responsive site and the navbar work well on browser
2. now you open facebook app and go to that post. then click on link to xekhong.com inside the post. the page will be loaded in Ifram(I guess so) and the navbar will not work. 
3. The code above is simply html of the navbar button using boostrap